# How to show list of components in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm building a multiplayer game which when connecting to the server, the server sends back a list of available rooms (each room has MaxPlayers,MinRank,TableId,TableName,Password) so everytime I recieve these 5 strings, I create an instance of Mxml UI Component I have created and fill it with the relevant details.

In the main.MXML i've added an AS3 script variable to hold the GameInstances object i've created when rcvd data back from the server:

```
private var gameInstances:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
```

GameInstance.mxml is a component that has UI components in it and AS3 script to set some data.
When rcving data from the server in main.mxml :

```
var gameInstance:GameInstance = new GameInstance();
gameInstance.setTablePlayers(rcvdMsg[1]);
gameInstance.setTableMinRank(rcvdMsg[2]);
gameInstance.setTableId(rcvdMsg[3]);
gameInstance.setTableName(rcvdMsg[4]);
gameInstance.setTablePassword(rcvdMsg[5]);
gameInstances.addItem(gameInstance);
```

gameInstances holds objects of that mxml component.
How do I show this component visualy on the main.mxml?
I have a  in main.mxml that I want visually show inside it the GameInstance objects.

This is how GameInstance.mxml looks like, I want the s:List to hold for each game a UI object like that(to show it ofcourse)
[image]

Comment: Please reword your question it is hard to understand.

Comment: @The_asMan, I've edited, let me know if it's clear enough, thx

Comment: Can you post the code on how you generate your array collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, if you using the gameInstances arraycollection as a data provider for tableList then you need to do a few things.
First, you need to make your gameInstances arraycollection [Bindable]

Then, you need to add data to the array collection as code you posted shows you are.

Next, you have to Create a custom item renderer for your tableList.

Finally, when you are done changing data/adding/removing objects from the gameInstances arraycollection you need to gameInstances.refresh();

[EDIT]
create a file named myListRenderer.mxml and put this code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:VBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

  <mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[

  override protected function commitProperties():void{
    // this is where you assign your values
    // this function gets called every-time  the list scrolls
    super.commitProperties();
    players.text =  this.data.setTablePlayers
    minRank.text =  this.data.setTableMinRank;
    tableId.text =  this.data.setTableId;
    tableName.text =  this.data.setTableName;
    tablePassword.text =  this.data.setTablePassword;
  }

]]>
</mx:Script>

  <mx:Label id="players" />
  <mx:Label id="minRank" />
  <mx:Label id="tableId" />
  <mx:Label id="tableName" />
  <mx:Label id="tablePassword" />

</mx:VBox>
```

Comment: Thanks, making arraycollection bindable is just by adding [Bindable] one live above the array collection declaration? and how to create an item renderer for my s:List id="tableList" ?

Comment: Yes that is how to declare a var bindable. o0n your list add itemRenderer="myListRenderer" would point to myListRenderer.as

Comment: Check out the edit I made for you. I am not sure about the data structure for your gameInstance object but this would be how to show strings.

Comment: Lol yes sorry I did say .as I meant mxml

Comment: If my gameInstances arraycollection has GameInstance objects inside it, how do I set it as a data provider?  also, does the GameInstance.mxml Ive created can serve as item renderer?

Comment: s:List id="tableList" dataProvider="gameInstances"

Comment: when i set the dataprovider that way, i just get the display to look like that: GameInstance 20 , GameInstance 105, and it doesn't show the different data

Comment: Alon The item renderer will pull data from the GameInstance and assign the data to the field you never posted your GameInstance class so I guessed when I posted the renederer you have to adjust it to your needs

Comment: Hi, in the item renderer I get: 1120: Access of undefined property ScrollBar

Comment: oops take out the function hbox_clickHandler completely I forgot to remove it and it doesn't belong there

Comment: how do I use the commitProperties() function in the itemRenderer?

Comment: read the comment I supplied in the function :) you don't call it it will get called automatically.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4291/discussion-between-alon-and-the-asman)

Comment: Hi, can the item renderer be done with spark components ? I'm trying to do it with s:Label but the it only works with mx:Label.

Comment: You specify the data for the List control by using the dataProvider property of the control. You may have to change the item reneder to spark type. I am at work on flex 3 so I cant look into it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, when you create components in ActionScript, you have to add them to a container before they'lls how up in the UI.  If you have an array of components, you can just loop over that array and add each component as a child on a container.  The main application file is a container, so you can do something like this:

```
for each(var myComp:UIComponent in myArrayList){
  addChild(myComp);
}
```

It would be unusual to take this approach.  Usually you just add the component to the parent container as you create them.

Comment: Hi, I have <s:List id="tableList" includeIn="LobbyState" x="31" y="92" width="449" height="198"></s:List> which is a UI component I've dragged from the palette and I've created a new .mxml component file which is a square panel with some stuff in it and for each game instance I want to create an instance of that component and show it inside S:LIST, if I just created some instances of that component, it doesn't show in the s:LIST, what am I missing?

Comment: @Alon I don't understand.  Add some full code to your question.

Comment: Objects returned from the server that contain five string properties will have no visual appearance. They're just, in essence, data containers.  How do you want to display the data?

Comment: I have <s:List> mxml element, rectangle, i want it to fill with GameInstances objects (GameInstance is a MXML UI component)

Comment: Basically, instead of showing a datagrid which eachline represent and show a game table, I want to have it display a nice UI component for each GameTable, a square component with text in it and if I have few gametables in the server, then I will see few square components like that.

Comment: I'm no longer sure what your actual question is.  But I think you need to create an itemRenderer to display your data elements and then set the values returned from your service as the dataProvider to the list.